# Queries related to NSURLConnection delegate methods

Tags: iphone, deprecated, ios5, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am developing an iPhone application that uses NSURLConnection for fetching some network content. My iPhone application should work on iOS >= 4.1

(1) Are the following delegate methods available in all the iOS >= 4.1 including iOS5 (Beta).

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

The documentation mentions that these methods are 'Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3' and are listed under the section 'Deprecated NSURLConnection methods' of iOS5 documentation. (However when I command+Click on these methods, are listed under Foundation framework of iOS5.0 Library)

(2) When we call `[<NSURLConnection_object> cancel]`, is the request cancelled immediately OR do we get any callbacks when the request is actually cancelled? Is it safe to release NSURLConnection_object immediately after the call to cancel?

Comment: See the accepted answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862316/ios5-nsurlconnection-methods-deprecated

Comment: @Vin: Got the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862316/ios5-nsurlconnection-methods-deprecated

Comment: Isn't that the same link I posted?

Comment: Yes. But, since it is in comment I am not able to accept your answer.

Comment: write your findings as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think they should work and working fine for me. Even they are commented like you said in `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, they are looking fine in `NSURLConnection` doc. So I hope they should work. I am saying this because they are working for me in IOS 5.