# Deprecated NSURLConnection Methods, is there an alternative?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am setting up a NSURLConnection to access a remote server:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:projectURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Using the following delegate methods below:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
```

All of theses methods say "Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3." My question should I be doing this another way for the current iOS5? I need asynchronous transfer and need to pass a NSURLCredential for UID/PWD authentication.

## EDIT:

So if I am adopting the protocol `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>` in my header and using the delegate methods above I am doing this the right way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS5 NSURLConnection methods deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862316/ios5-nsurlconnection-methods-deprecated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iOS 5, looks like you can take advantage of the new [`NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (documentation linked for you).

[And here's a related (or maybe even duplicate?) question that explains even better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862316/ios5-nsurlconnection-methods-deprecated).

Comment: Yep, they're still around, they've just been moved to a formal protocol.

Comment: Hm, actually, all those methods are missing from the protocol's docs for some reason; they still exist (and are non-deprecated), though! Searching the web points to this being a documentation bug.

Comment: You're welcome, fuzzy.  Adding `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>` to your header *should* work for both the formal and informal protocol usage, but I have to wonder if the compiler will throw any "warning" complaints.  Hopefully not.