# how to wait till a modal dialog returns a result in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a custom `UIViewController` shown with `presentModalViewController` function in a http basic authentication delegate to get username and password. I want to wait till the user clicked the login button on the modal view controller shown on the screen. How can I do this? I am new to iOS any comments or links would be appreciated.

Edit : here is a sample code inside `NSURLConnectionDelegate`

```
-(void) connection(NSURLConnection*)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge*)challenge
{
    CustomAuthViewController *authView = [CustomAuthViewController alloc] initWithNibName"@"CustomAuthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [parentcontroller presentModalViewController:authView animated:YES];
    // 
    // I want to wait here somehow till the user enters the username/password
    //
    [[challenge sender] userCredentials:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Kind regards.

Edit : Solution : It is not necessary to send the credentials in the willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge delegate function right away. I can send it anytime later, It is strange though.

Comment: You can dismiss the modalViewController once the user clicked the button, ist that what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately no!!! I am showing a custom UIViewController to gather user/password in a willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge function. Now I have to wait till the user type the user/password and click the login button the view... otherwise I will not be able to send the userCredentials:forAuthenticationChallenge  in the next line after presentModalViewController :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what you want is to pass a message from the modal UIViewController to the caller when your login dialog completes. There are a number of ways to do this. Here's a couple:

Option 1 - Delegate Pattern:

On your modal dialog .h

```
@protocol LoginDelegate
- (void)loginComplete:(NSString *)userId;
- (void)loginFailed;
@end

@interface MyLoginDialog : UIViewController {
    UIViewController *delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *delegate;
```

On your modal dialog .m

in your init:

```
delegate = nil;
```

in your dealloc:

```
[delegate release];
```

when you complete your login:

```
[delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
[delegate loginComplete:userId] or [delegate loginFailed];
```

Then on your calling view controller implement the LoginDelegate protocol.

And when you create your login view controller, set the delegate:

```
UIViewController *viewLogin = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewLogin.delegate = self;
```

Option 2 - Post a notification with NSNotificationCenter:

On your login dialog:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoginComplete" object:nil];
```

On your calling view controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginComplete:) name:@"LoginComplete" object:nil];
```

Then you implement the selector loginComplete.

If you want to pass back login information (username, userId, etc) you can package that into a dictionary and add it as the "object" in the postNotificationName method.

You also need to be sure to call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

when you are done listening.

Comment: Hi Joel, Thanks for your efforts, I really appreciate it. The willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge function is asking for the userCredentials, so after I show the dialog with presentModalViewController function how will I wait ??? if not,  the next line for sending the credentials will get executed.

Comment: You don't ever "wait" inside a code block for an asyn operation. You implement willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge in the callback method when the login dialog is completed.

Comment: May be I am missing something !!! The NSURLConnection calls the willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge, when that happens I should show the dialog. There is no point in showing the dialog before. After I show it the code execution goes on. May be I am totally confuesd, if you can please send me a code snippet... I have also put some code on the original question.

Comment: You probably want to implement didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge not willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge. didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge will suspend the execution until you pass back the credentials.

Comment: So you do, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge then show your dialog, then when your dailog calls back that it is done, you call useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge suspend the execution. The documentation says that didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is deprecated from iOS 4.0 should use willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge.  Do you know how to do it with willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge ?

Comment: The documentation is a mess. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862316/ios5-nsurlconnection-methods-deprecated. You may just want to implement the old ones for now. They are still supported and work fine.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that link. Still I don't really have the idea how to call the dialog to get username/password and send the credentials back ? should I send the credentials later some where in the event handler of the login button ? I think by that time the connection will give back a connection error, doesn't it ?

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. Thanks for your efforts and time.