# Download with NSURLConnection returns empty data?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

My app is downloading a file from the internet using NSURLConnection.

Two problems are happening:

1) [connection didReceiveData] is never called

2) When [connection didFinishDownloading] is called, my self.currentData is empty

What am I doing wrong?

My header looks like this:

```
@interface DIFileDownloader : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate> {

    NSMutableData *currentData;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DIFileDownloaderDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *supportedFormats;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *currentData;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *downloadAgent;

@property (nonatomic) long long expectedContentSize;

@property (nonatomic) float currentDownloadProgress;

@property (nonatomic, getter = isRunning) BOOL running;

-(instancetype)initWithSupportedFormats:(NSArray *)extensions;

-(void)downloadFileAtURL:(NSURL *)url;

-(NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath;

@end
```

And my implementation file:

```
-(instancetype)initWithSupportedFormats:(NSArray *)extensions {

    self.supportedFormats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:extensions];

    self.running = NO;
}

-(void)downloadFileAtURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSString *fileExtension = [url pathExtension];

    if ([self.supportedFormats containsObject:fileExtension]) {

        self.downloadAgent = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] delegate:self];

        [self.downloadAgent start];

        NSLog(@"Beginning download at URL:%@", url.absoluteString);

    }
    else {

    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Connection recieved response with size: %f", (float)[response expectedContentLength]);

    self.expectedContentSize = (float)[response expectedContentLength];

    self.running = YES;

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

    NSLog(@"%i", [httpResponse statusCode]);

    /*

    if ([httpResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [httpResponse statusCode] <= 299) {

    }

     */

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSLog(@"%f", (float)[data length]);

    [currentData appendData:data];

    self.currentDownloadProgress = ((float)[data length] / self.currentDownloadProgress);

    NSLog(@"Connection recieved data. New progress is: %f", self.currentDownloadProgress);

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloader:progressChanged:)]) {
        [self.delegate downloader:self progressChanged:self.currentDownloadProgress];
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Connection failed");

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloader:failedToDownloadFileAtURL:reason:)]) {
        [self.delegate downloader:self failedToDownloadFileAtURL:connection.originalRequest.URL reason:error];
    }

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL {

    NSLog(@"Connection finished downloading with size: %f", (float)[currentData length]);

    self.running = NO;

    NSString *filename = [destinationURL.absoluteString lastPathComponent];

    NSString *docPath = [self documentsDirectoryPath];

    NSString *pathToDownloadTo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, filename];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [currentData writeToFile:pathToDownloadTo options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {

        NSLog(@"DIFileDownloader: Failed to save the file because: %@", [error description]);

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloader:failedToDownloadFileAtURL:reason:)]) {
            [self.delegate downloader:self failedToDownloadFileAtURL:connection.originalRequest.URL reason:error];
        }

} 
    else {

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloader:finishedDownloadingFileNamed:atPath:)]) {
            [self.delegate downloader:self finishedDownloadingFileNamed:filename atPath:pathToDownloadTo];
        }

    }

}

- (NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectoryPath;
}

@end
```

Comment: Well, for one thing you never create your `NSMutableData` object.

Comment: And then it looks like you have the same problem as [NSURLConnection connection:didReceiveData: is not called on ios5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085007/nsurlconnection-connectiondidreceivedata-is-not-called-on-ios5) There's also another useful answer at [NSURLConnection didReceiveData: didn't get called iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14553538)

Comment: There are a number of bugs in your code: your init method is not according the rules, and doesn't return the object. The way you calculate `currentDownloadProgress` isn't working, and a few more. I would suggest to add quite a lot of assertions and error checks in your code and, and then start your debugging sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in others and in my comment, there are a few bugs in your code which you need to fix.

But there is also one big misconception - stemming from the former awful documentation of `NSURLConnection`:

`connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:` is NOT a delegate method of the two delegates of NSURLConnection namely, `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` which you are supposed to implement in your case.

The minimal set of delegate methods you need to implement are:

For the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`:

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

then for the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`:

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection;

If you don't mind, I've put a sample of a minimal implementation on Gist: [SimpleGetHTTPRequest](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/5764723) which should give you a jump start do implement your own HTTP request class.

Comment: Thanks for that sample, I think i've got what I need!